# a 'C' in the status line of vim

Tags: vim

I noticed a 'C' in the status line (bottom line) when I opened /etc/passwd with vim. What does this 'C' stand for? I don't see this 'C' when I open other files (e.g., /etc/hosts).

Comment: Where is the 'C'?  I see one at the end of the status line, but also for `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Could you post your config, and maybe even a screenshot? Can't reproduce with `$ vim -u NONE -U NONE /etc/passwd`. It's probably related to your `set statusline` or something.

Comment: I see one, when I open _any_ fil,e at the end of a number, indicating it's the number of characters in the file.

Comment: It should look more like `"/etc/hosts" [readonly] 17L, 392C`, but it seems cut off.

Comment: There is only a "C", no numbers or anything else. But when I open other files, there is nothing at all in the bottom line.

Comment: That looks like the number of character in the file that @mbratch was talking about. Can you highlight the line? it seems the color you are using is the same as the background

Comment: Yeah, it looks like there's a font color issue making the preceding text of the line nearly or totally invisible. It is very odd that you don't see the 'C' with other files, though.

Comment: You guys are right. When I adjusted the window size, the "C" was gone. And then I quit vim and open the file again, I saw "/etc/passwd" 32L, 1446C". It seems to be a display problem in the Terminal of MacOS. When I adjusted the window size again, the whole "/etc/passwd" 32L, 1446C" was gone, and highlight the line didn't help.

Comment: @Runner [You could answer your own question, and mark it as accepted after two days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a display problem of the Terminal in MacOS. When I adjusted the window size, the "C" was gone. And then I quit vim and open the file again, I saw "/etc/passwd" 32L, 1446C". Then I adjusted the window size again, this time the whole "/etc/passwd" 32L, 1446C" was gone, and highlight the line didn't show them up.